# How to write an excel file with Python and to add to each row of a column an intent followed by the same string?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Hi I have the code above to write an excel file:

```py
def write_excel(df):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("PATH\output.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')  

    workbook=writer.book
    worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet('sheet')
    writer.sheets['sheet'] = worksheet

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet', startcol = 0, startrow = 0)
    writer.save()

write_excel(df)
```

df is a dataframe looking like:

```
ID             NUMBER      OBJECT
1345471886     SIZE-43     GHJ
1481654311     SIZE-48     IJF  
8620787660     SIZE-67     EFH
```

and I added this code below to add an indent and the string "hello you, hello" to the column OBJECT :

```
def add_agg_columns(df):
    df["OBJECT"] = df["OBJECT"] + "\n\nhello you, hello\n" 
    
    return df
```

I get:

```
ID             NUMBER      OBJECT
1345471886     SIZE-43     GHJ\n\nhello you, hello\n
1481654311     SIZE-48     IJF\n\nhello you, hello\n  
8620787660     SIZE-67     EFH\n\nhello you, hello\n
```

In my excel file I would like my final output to look like:

```
ID             NUMBER      OBJECT
1345471886     SIZE-43     GHJ

                           hello you, hello
1481654311     SIZE-48     IJF
                        
                           hello you, hello
8620787660     SIZE-67     EFH

                           hello you, hello
```

but what I get when I write the excel file at the moment is only:

```
ID             NUMBER      OBJECT
1345471886     SIZE-43     GHJ
1481654311     SIZE-48     IJF  
8620787660     SIZE-67     EFH
```

Comment: I just tried your function and seemed to work fine. The file produced definitely included all the text it was supposed to include. How are you checking the file output? How are you creating the dataframe? Would you like to post a [mre]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below actually fixed it!

```
last_sentence = """ 
hello you, hello
"""

def add_agg_columns(df):
    df["OBJECT"] = df["OBJECT"] + last_sentence 
    
    return df

def write_excel(df):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("PATH\output.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')  

    workbook=writer.book
    worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet('sheet')
    writer.sheets['sheet'] = worksheet

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet', startcol = 0, startrow = 0)
    writer.save()

write_excel(df)
```